# CSS: Overlapping Unordered Vertical List

Tags: html, css, html-lists, navigationbar

Please check out the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zzy7h0te/3/).

```css
.sideNav {
  width: 25%;
}
.sideNav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
}
.sideNav li a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sideNav li {
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
.right {
  width: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="sideNav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="curriculum.html">Curriculum</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="ersea.html">ERSEA</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="family-services.html">Family Services</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="mental-health.html">Mental Health</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="nutrition.html">Nutrition</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="health.html">Health</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="policies.html">Policies &amp; Procedures</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="ersea.html">ERSEA</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="family-services.html">Family Services</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="mental-health.html">Mental Health</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="nutrition.html">Nutrition</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    This is a test
  </div>
</div>
```

I am having an issue with my CSS unordered list links. The links are not appearing on their own, separate lines. For instance, Link1 (Curriculum) is running into Link2 (ERSEA), so-on and so-forth. Also, I created two `<div>` tags, setting one to 25% of the div and the other to 75% of div. However, they are interfering with one another, as you can see from my fiddle, the "This is a test" text appears behind my unordered list.

I need my side navigation bar to be fixed in one position and have all of the links on their own separate lines. In addition, I need to have the "This is a test" text appear in its own separate portion of the site; to the right of the side navigation bar.

Comment: Add float: right; to the "right" class. Though using position: fixed isn't good practise since Apple doesn't support it well.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues:

1. you have set your li:s to `float: left`, this will cause them to merge together.
2. you have set the .sideNav to have `position: fixed`, this means that it will not be calculated into the "flow" of the rest of the items on the site and therefore sit on top of them.

Here's a little updated css to help you along a little...

```css
.sideNav {
  width: 25%;
}

.sideNav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
}

.sideNav li a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sideNav li {
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

.right {
  padding-left: 25%;
  width: 75%;
}
```